# how to extract column by removing delimiter in bash script

Tags: bash

Having a huge file in which columns are separated by |~| delimiter.
How to extract required number of columns using shell command ?
Lets say File looks like :

```
column1|~|column2|~|column3|~|column4|~|column5|~|column6|~|column7
```

and we want to extract column 4 and 5

Comment: What have you tried so far? I suggest thinking about what generic steps you would take to solve your problem and how you'd implement these individually before asking a high level question like this. E.g. how to declare an array in bash, how to split a string based on a delimiter in bash, how to read a file line by line in bash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
awk -F "(|~|)" '{ print $4,$5 }' file
```

Set the field delimiter as "|~|" with -F and then print the 4th and 5th fields ($4,$5)

Answer (score 0):

In plain `bash`:

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS= read -r line; do
    readarray -t fields <<< "${line//'|~|'/$'\n'}"
    printf '%s %s\n' "${fields[3]}" "${fields[4]}"
done < file
```

or, with `awk`

```
awk -F '\\|~\\|' '{ print $4, $5 }' file
```

or, with GNU `sed`:

```
sed -E 's/\|~\|/\n/g; s/([^\n]*\n){3}(([^\n]*\n){2}).*/\2/; s/\n/ /g' file
```